# Why is there a project management tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

I noticed that there is a tag [project-management](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management). This should be explicitly off-topic and there is even a dedicated site for such questions, https://pm.stackexchange.com/. Notably, almost no question using the tag is actually about project management.

It's just 25 questions so I can clean this up myself with edits, but posting here before I go ahead. I'd do this according to the [SO tag removal process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) which (TL;DR) basically means not just blindly removing the tag from every post, but also reviewing each post to see if it should be edited, closed or if other tags needs changing while at it. I trust that the same method is sensible to follow on EE as well.

Comment: I would imagine that there are some project-management questions that are specificly electrical engineering related? What a more 'business management' person would consider 'project management', and what a engineer considers project management, might diverge on a number of points?

Comment: @JorenVaes Any specific example? Because even if there are project management questions that EE specific, I don't think they are on-topic still. What comes to my mind as specific is BOM cost questions, or which brands and suppliers that are reliable etc, but that boils down to shopping/buyer recommendations. Stuff like "never specify TI because they have no customer support" is definitely something EE specific that comes from long experience of dealing with a crappy vendor, but it is very much off-topic regardless.

Comment: Mass tag edits are generally a pain in the arse though. The front page is now full of old questions.

Comment: @SiHa Yeah indeed, I am completely aware of the ruckus it creates, which is why we should bring such up here on meta first. But it was relatively few questions and I'm done now, so it will return to normal very soon. (This site has so many bad tags though, it's as if nobody has moderated tags for 10 years... I came across lots of other crap tags like "design", "development", "3d", "component"... )

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nobody has voiced any major concern for one week, I went ahead and cleaned up the 25 posts, as far as I could.

I have close-voted or flagged off-topic posts as I come across them. The on-topic posts that were regarding version control of EE projects could be re-tagged or did not need the project-management tag. (Notably, version control questions are on-topic at SO, so maybe that's a better place for such, even if EE related?)

Those 7 that remain are questions where project management was the only tag. They need more close votes or delete votes, as they are all off-topic.

I'm also hesitating about what to do with a really old but highly up-voted tool recommendation question: [Version control systems for hardware projects?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8767/version-control-systems-for-hardware-projects). It is off-topic by the today's standards for the site, but may be a suitable fit for a "historical lock", if we want to preserve it.

I added a "DO NOT USE" tag wiki here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/project-management/info.

I won't do anything further with this tag now, but leave it to moderators to deal with as they see fit.

Comment: Once the questions have been re-tagged, the tag can be deleted (let me or another mod know). Thank you for your help

Comment: @VoltageSpike If this site works like the rest of them, the tag will automatically get removed when no questions have it any longer. Those that remain are those that only hold this single tag. Pretty much all of them old questions about project management posted when the site had lax standards.

Comment: All of the questions are now closed except for "Keeping digital logbooks for individual projects", where I am the only close vote. I'm not sure what else to tag it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the questions, I see three basic groups:

- Questions that are about project management.
- Questions that are actually about working with software projects in IDEs and CAD tools (e.g. Eclipse projects).
- Questions about something totally unrelated, probably because someone typed "X project" into the tabs field.

I found nine non-closed questions in the first category. Many of them sound like shopping questions ("What tool could I use for this?") or discussion questions ("What does your organization do for this?"), and should perhaps be closed. (One probably belongs on Interpersonal.) None of the questions are newer than 2013.

I don't see any reason to keep this tag. No one is using it for good questions about project management. I suggest closing all the open project management questions, changing or removing the tag on the IDE/CAD questions, and removing the tag from the other questions.

Comment: Agree, I took a glance at the questions posted too and many were already closed. Those regarding tools should be re-tagged to use the appropriate tool tag indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the questions that had the project-management tags are from the EE.SE 1.0 days and are 8-10 years old. The questions still have value,so they need not be deleted (also, it is not necessary to go back and find old questions to be closed, if there are problems with old questions (like people posting bad answers, then they should be closed). The questions cannot be moved, as only questions up to 1 month old can be moved to a different site. The questions will need to be retagged, do you best on the retagging.